# \graphicspath for Inkscape pdf_tex files

Tags: input

For writing a lecture note, I have put my images in a subdirectory named "image". In the `main.tex` file I have added `\graphicspath{{image/}}`. I have also included:

```
\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
 \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
 {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0%
 {\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi%
}

\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
 \executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}%
 {inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg %
 --export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex}%
 \input{#1.pdf_tex}%
}
```

in order to include `pdf_tex` files.

In the `main.tex` file I am inserting the SVG file by:

```
\begin{figure}
\input{filename.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `relativeposition.pdf_tex' not found.
```

Can anyone tell me what I should do to keep all my SVG files in the image subdirectory and input them from `main.tex`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Wouldn't it be simpler if you say `\input{image/filename.pdf_tex}`? In case of only one subdirectory it's not so heavy.

Comment: writing \input{image/filename.pdf_tex} is not working i am getting the same error as the one mentioned above

Answer (score 6):

A quick hack that allows you to write

```
\svginput{relativeposition.pdf_tex}
```

taking into account all subpaths defined with `\graphicspath` is to add

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\svginput}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:cn { Ginput@path }
   {
    \InputIfFileExists{##1#1}{ \tl_map_break: } { }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

to your document preamble.

However, if only one subdirectory is defined in `\graphicspath` it's probably easier to define

```
\newcommand{\svginput}[1]{\input{image/#1}}
```

where you simply add `image` (or the name you want to give to the subdirectory).

Comment: Concerning your second suggestion should i add only the \newcommand{
\svginput}[1]{\input{image/#1}} or i should add the \usepackage{xparse} also to the preamble. \\ another question when using \svginput should i use it beside an \begin{figure} \svginput{relativeposition.pdf_tex} \end{figure}

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have followed your answer and it is working now.