# LaTeX comfortable usage of vectorgraphics

Tags: pdf, texmaker, svg

Right now I am writing a project paper (with TexMaker in LaTeX), therefore I need vectorgraphics (created them with Inkscape). After saving, there were three files created:

- 1x *.svg
- 1x *.pdf
- 1x *pdf_tex

The folder structure of my project folder looks like:

```
project/    --> place of my project.tex
project/chapter/ --> folder for chapters of my project
[...]
project/graphics/ --> all graphics go here
project/graphics/beta/ --> place were my right now used graphics are saved
project/graphics/NACA/
[...]
```

My LaTeX preamble looks like:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{svg}
```

Graphics are used in my documentation right now by LaTeX like:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{300pt}
    \input{Grafiken/beta/bsp.pdf_tex}
    \caption{topview} 
\label{img:BSPmodell}
\end{figure}
```

At the savin process there are graphics saved as *.pdf, they are needed for the include process of the graphics. Right now, I can't let this file stay in the same folder which the *.svg and *.pdf_tex-file sharing together, I have to copy that file manually to the project folder.

*Now the qestion:*

**Which configuration do I need that every .pdf file of the vectorgraphics could stay in the same folder as the other two files?**

Right now, as described before, my files (*.svg and *.pdf_tex) are placed in `project/graphics/beta` and the *.pdf file need to stay in the main project folder to be recognized in the compiling process. While working I need to copy the file always manually, created now a batch to do this, but the main project folder gets more and more confusing while the project grows.

I prefer the *.svg, *.pdf_tex and *.pdf should stay toghether in the same folder, the Latex (TexMaker) should recognize the *.pdf file there by itself.

**Sorry, I'm new here and forgot to translate everything in English. I rewrote my question :)**

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that this site is English, you can get help in German for instance on https://texwelt.de/fragen/. That being said, I'm not entirely sure how Inkscape includes the pdf, but guess it's using `graphicx`, in which case you can use `\graphicspath{{Projektarbeit/Grafiken/beta/}}`.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm sorry, I translated it manually right now to fit the platform :) Next time I am going to write it directly in english.

Comment: No harm done, you weren't the first and certainly are not going to be the last person who posts in another language. Btw. did the `\graphicspath` suggestion work?

Comment: @Skillmon now the compiler don't find any graphics right now. I changed every usega of the path everywere from e.g. `graphics/beta/picture.png` to `logo.PNG` or e.g. `beta/picture1.png`.

Comment: You could see whether https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77690/graphicspath-for-inkscape-pdf-tex-files helps.